# How to filter for minimum date and remove duplicate dates in joined table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to join three tables with the parent table to get an output of **customer id**, **visit id**, and **visit date** where the oldest date is selected if more than one date. All four tables contain the cust_id, visit_id, and visit_date variables, but visit_id is the linking variable. I named the four tables a, b, c, and d to simplify the code below (a is the parent table).

My current code below gets me closer to my desired output, but I'm not sure how to get one **visit_date** column with the oldest date by **visit_id** and am unsure on how to remove duplicates. Any help will be sincerely appreciated, and please let me know if I can clarify anything!

```
SELECT
    a.cust_id,
    a.visit_id,
    a.visit_date,
    b.visit_date,
    c.visit_date,
    d.visit_date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a.visit_id = b.visit_id
LEFT JOIN c
    ON a.visit_id = c.visit_id
LEFT JOIN d
    ON a.visit_id = d.visit_id
WHERE a.visit_date IS NOT NULL
OR b.visit_date IS NOT NULL
OR c.visit_date IS NOT NULL
OR d.visit_date IS NOT NULL;
```

My current output looks like this:

| cust_id | visit_id | visit_date | visit_date | visit_date | visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 2013-05-23 |  |  |  |
| 002 | 002 |  | 2013-06-03 | 2013-05-27 |  |
| 003 | 003 | 2013-06-05 | 2013-06-05 | 2013-06-05 |  |
| 003 | 004 |  | 2013-07-09 | 2013-07-09 | 2013-07-06 |

My desired output looks like this:

| cust_id | visit_id | visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 2013-05-23 |
| 002 | 002 | 2013-05-27 |
| 003 | 003 | 2013-06-05 |
| 003 | 004 | 2013-07-06 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the scalar `LEAST` function:

```sql
SELECT
    a.cust_id,
    a.visit_id,
    LEAST(a.visit_date, b.visit_date, c.visit_date, d.visit_date) AS visit_date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a.visit_id = b.visit_id
LEFT JOIN c
    ON a.visit_id = c.visit_id
LEFT JOIN d
    ON a.visit_id = d.visit_id
WHERE
    a.visit_date IS NOT NULL OR
    b.visit_date IS NOT NULL OR
    c.visit_date IS NOT NULL OR
    d.visit_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, you beautiful human being. This works, thank you.